# Bash at and $DISPLAY, howto?

Tags: python, bash, environment

I'm working on a Python GUI application and at some point I need to be defering the execution of big parts of Python code. I have tried using `at` for doing it :

```
line = 'echo "python ./executor.py ibm ide graph" | at -t 1403211632'
subprocess.Popen(line,Shell=True)
```

This line gives no error and effectively starts the job at the given time.

Now, each option for `executor.py` is a job it has to do, and each job is protected with a try/catch log. In some cases I catch this error :

```
14-03-21_17:07:00 starting ibm for Simulations/140321170659
Failed to execute ibm : no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
Aborted the whole execution.
```

I have tried the following, thinking I could provide the $DISPLAY to the environement, with no success (same error):

```
line = 'DISPLAY=:0.0;echo "python ./executor.py Simulations/140321170936 eid defer" | at -t 1403211711'
```

From `man at` :

```
The working  directory, the environment (except for the variables BASH_VERSINFO, DISPLAY, EUID, GROUPS, SHELLOPTS, TERM, UID, and _) and the umask are retained from the time of invocation.
```

### Question :

- What can possibly be causing this error to raise ?
- How do I provide the $DISPLAY variable to `at`'s environement ?

### Solution :

I actually needed to put `export DISPLAY=:0.0` inside echo so that it is set after `at` had started his environnement.

```
line = echo "export DISPLAY=:0.0; python..." | at...
subprocess.Popen(line,Shell=True)
```

Comment: try `export DISPLAY=0.0`

Comment: Tried with both `export DISPLAY=0.0` and `export DISPLAY=:0.0`. Same error.

Comment: My bad for thinking wrong. `export DISPLAY=:0.0; echo "python..." | at ...` does not work. `echo "export DISPLAY=:0.0; python..." | at...` DOES work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set `DISPLAY` in the python script by taking the current environment, adding the DISPLAY setting and passing the new environment to the sub-shell created by Popen.

```
import os;
new_env = dict(os.environ)
new_env['DISPLAY'] = '0.0'
...
...
subprocess.Popen(line, env=new_env, Shell=True)
```

Comment: I do get exactly the same error. I think `at` is simply running in his own place, detached from the Shell where I invoked the command. You can close the Shell, but the job is still pending and `at` will start it anyways, without $DISPLAY.

Comment: We got the solution, we had to set the variable after `at` had started his environnement. Edited my post for showing the solution.